# Redux - Find object in state array by its key and update its another key

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am working on a CRUD app using NodeJS in backend and React + Redux in frontend. This is a quick schema of how everything works in it:

**Adding an item**

1. User inputs the title of a post
2. Title is then sent to dispatch which fetches a `POST` route in NodeJS and sends title through body
3. In NodeJS route i am adding a new item in collection with that title

**BACKEND DONE, new post is in the server**

4. I am adding `.then()` on dispatch function in step 2. in which I dispatch an action with `type: 'ADD_POST'` and `post: post` (i got post from NodeJS `res.json({post: result from database})`)
5. In my reducer i set up a `CASE 'ADD_POST': return action.post`

**FRONTEND DONE, the same post is now visible to user without refreshing**

I want to use the same logic to update the **likes** of a specific post. This is what I've done so far:

1. Clicking on a button on a post triggers a dispatch which fetches NodeJS `PUT` route
2. NodeJS route finds the post using ID and adds 1 to the old value of likes the post had

**BACKEND DONE, post now has 1 more like in the server**

3. I am adding `.then` again to the dispatch which fetches NodeJS route in which I dispatch an action with `type 'ADD_LIKE'` and `post ID` that I updated
4. in reducer I set up a `CASE 'ADD_LIKE':` which iterates through the state using the code in the following snippet.

Here's that snippet:

```
state.map(item => {
    if(item.id === action.postid) {
      //i find the specific item, but now im stuck on how to update the likes property of it
    }
})
```

If it helps, this is the playlist I've been watching, if you want to you can see how this guy implements Delete function, I want to add Likes function using the same logic: [Link to playlist](https://youtu.be/Hokb82qiM1E)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
state.map(item => {
    if (item.id !== action.postid) return item; // no need to change other items
    const likes = item.likes;
    return Object.assign({}, item, {likes: likes + 1}); // [1]
});
```

Line `[1]` creates a new object with all the same properties of `item`, but it overwrites the existing property `likes` and simply adds `1`.

Make sure you actually create a new object for the changed item in the reducer, as everything in your state should be immutable.